# Leaflet Popups with Clojurescript

Tags: leaflet, clojurescript

I'm pretty sure this is a conceptual error, but I'm not sure where I'm making the incorrect call.

Following the leaflet tutorial, I'm trying to create a popup on a map. Per the tutorial, this is a simple operation

```
var popup = L.popup();

function onMapClick(e) {
    popup
        .setLatLng(e.latlng)
        .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
        .openOn(mymap);
}

mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
```

However, when I translate this into clojurescript, I receive the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: t.openPopup is not a function

I'm 100% positive I'm calling the javascript incorrectly. I'm doing the following:

```
(defn onMapClick [e]
  (let [popup (js/L.Popup.)]
    (-> popup
        (.setLatLng (.-latlng e))
        (.setContent (str "You clicked the map at " (.-latlng e)))
        (.openOn map))))
```

And then I call this as:

```
(.on map "click" onMapClick)
```

where `map` is correctly defined. (I say correctly because I am able to draw polygons and create popups that are bound to those polygons with `.bindPopup`)

Comment: Have you tried it without the threading macro? The threading macro assumes that popup is returned each time, which might not be the case with these interop calls.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Unfortunately, `(.openOn popup (.setContent (.setLatLng popup (.-latlng e) "You clicked the map at " + (.-latlng e))) map)` yields the same error.

Comment: Turns out I made a super stupid mistake and was calling this outside the scope of where I define `map`, and it was breaking. Just wrap it in `(let [map ..define map..] <code here>)`

Comment: Not actually a great name to use anywhere, considering Clojure doesn't have great error messages and will allow shadowing: https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide#dont-shadow-clojure-core

Comment: @ChrisMurphy Sorry, that was just to clarify what was going on in leaflet, I've bound `(js/L.Map. "the-map")` to `leaflet-mp`.

Comment: I've just been reading Clojure source for `select-keys`. That function calls one of its parameters `map`.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of not relying on return values at all. Just relying on the call sequence:

```
(defn onMapClick [e]
  (let [popup (js/L.Popup.)]
    (.setLatLng popup (.-latlng e))
    (.setContent popup (str "You clicked the map at " (.-latlng e)))
    (.openOn popup map)))
```

If the docs say that these js setter functions return popup then this won't make much of an answer!

You should be able to isolate the problem down to just one function call??

Comment: Unfortunately, this throws the same error. Looking at the Leaflet code, it looks like it returns `openPopup` when passed some object, so I'm guessing I'm passing it the wrong object. I'll dig into it some more.

Comment: You could look at ClojureScript code that already uses Leaflet. Here is a possible resource, in case you haven't already found it: https://github.com/rururu/rete4flights